# Get maximum value of y value within a specified range of x value

Tags: python

I am using Python 3 in jupyter notebook and I data that looks like this:

```
x = [5100.   5100.05 5100.1  ... 5399.85 5399.9  5399.95] Angstrom
y = [1.83400998 1.26499399 0.85423358 ... 0.78314406 0.76861344 0.77460277]
```

Is there a way in Python 3 to grab the maximum y value for x between 5120 and 5250?

Comment: `max([a for b, a in zip(x, y) if 5120<=b<=5250])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200717/get-max-value-of-y-within-a-specified-range-of-x

Comment: @medium-dimensional I saw that post, but I am specifically looking for Python 3 solutions

Comment: The answers are the same regardless of version.